# Deployment group search

Tags: azure-devops

Can deployment groups be searched for a particular machine?  I need a way to find if a server is already part of a deployment group.  I can't tell from the group names if they are applicable to the project.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the REST API for [Deployment Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#deploymentgroup) and look in the [Machines property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#deploymentgroup).

Or, if you have access, you can open the deployment groups navigation and look at the targets.

[image]

You may want to employ a more robust implementation of tags for the machines in your deployment groups, so you know you'll only deploy to machines in the group that are applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was looking at using the REST API for deployment groups.  As to using the Azure portal to view the details, that would work if there were only a handful but as there are more than just a few, this isn't workable. If I may also ask, why are there, what appear to be, suffixes on the machine names?  I've noticed the same in my environment but not on all the targets.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use Rest API to list all deployment groups in a specific team project.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Conversely, it's not able to list all target groups for a special machine at present.

As a workaround, you can add a tag to a machine on the depoyment group configuration.

After that, **specify the tag at the release deployment group phase**.

This will make the release to choose all machine within the group deployment that match you tag.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think I have enough information now to accomplish my goal.